# Convert Network Blocks Transmitted to MB?

Tags: networking

I'd like to convert Blocks Transmitted (which is currently 7597090, my DSL modem states) to MB.  I don't know the size of each block though.  Also, the modem doesn't have any other bandwidth stats.  I'm hoping for a simple bc command line formula.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what the medium is for the interface you have a "transmitted block count" for ( am guessing you're looking at the WAN side, this will most likely be either Ethernet or ATM, depending on where you're located).

If it's ATM, it's (probably) a cell count, so 48 octets of payload per cell, but this will have both PPP and IP overhead, to some extent.

If it's Ethernet, it's between 576 and 1500 octets per frame. Again, there will be IP overhead (and there MAY be PPP overhead; as I understand it, most ethernet-based DSL solutions use PPPoE on the WAN side).

In short, there may or may not be an easy conversion, unless you can find an actual "octets transmitted" counter. It may be worth downloading something like tkmib and see what you can find in the way of supported MIBs on the router (rather than looking just at the admin interface; SNMP probing can, usually, find more counters on "consumer-level" kit).